# Convert unix time to readable date in pandas dataframe, using option ms

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm using the follwing expression

```
test = pd.to_datetime(1602705600000, unit='ms')
```

and check the result :

```
print(test) 
2020-10-24 20:00:00
```

But it should be `2020-10-24 20:00:00.000`

Comment: if you print something, this calls a certain representation (or string "format") of an object (`__str__` method) - here, just because fractional seconds aren't displayed doesn't mean they're not there.

Comment: your assertion should not rely on `print`; instead, it should look more like e.g. `assert pd.to_datetime(1602705600000, unit='ms') == pd.Timestamp("2020-10-24 20:00:00.000")`.

Comment: Thanks  a lot, it works